# how to add mongo option configuration to spring

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

My mongo config looks like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
        <constructor-arg name="addr" ref="address" />
        <constructor-arg name="options" ref="options" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="options" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
        <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWaitTime" value="500"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="address" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="X.X.X.X" />
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />

    </bean>
...
```

**Everything works well!**

**But** [In the Mongo XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd), there is written attribute named “threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier”. When I add this, I have such an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier' of bean class [com.mongodb.MongoOptions]: Bean property 'threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Do u know what happens? My new xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="options" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
    <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="100"/>
    <property name="threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxWaitTime" value="500"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is named **threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier** in com.mongodb.MongoOptions

```
<bean id="options" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
    <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="100"/>
    <property name="threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxWaitTime" value="500"/>
</bean>
```